# Session Variables error

Tags: c#, asp.net

**this is one of my page where i set up my session variable which I will use to store value**

```
protected void confirmImageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Session["confirmBooking"] = "confirm";
    Session["totalCost"] = toPayTextBox.Text;

    // If bachRadioButtonList SelectedValue != "Beach bach",
    // clear session variable, else set value to "Beach bach"
    Session["beachBach"] = (bachRadioButtonList.SelectedValue != "Beach bach");

    // If bachRadioButtonList SelectedValue != "Bush bach",
    // clear session variable, else set value to "Bush bach"
    Session["bushBach"] = (bachRadioButtonList.SelectedValue != "Bush bach");

    Response.Redirect("MainBookingform.aspx");
}
```

**and this is the page where I pull out those session variables:**

public partial class MainBookingform : System.Web.UI.Page

{

```
static int numberOfBeachBookingInteger = 0;

static int numberOfBushBookingInteger = 0;

static int totalRevenueInteger = 0;
```

public partial class MainBookingform : System.Web.UI.Page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        beachBachLabel.Text = numberOfBeachBookingInteger.ToString();
        bushBachLabel.Text = numberOfBushBookingInteger.ToString();

        if  ((Session["bushBach"] != null) && (Session["beachBach"] != null))
        {
            if (Session["beachBach"] != "confirm")
            {
                numberOfBeachBookingInteger += 1;
            }

            if (Session["bushBach"] != "confirm")
            {
                numberOfBushBookingInteger += 1;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

however, when I debug the program, it it doesn not add 1 to both the variable session: beachBach and bushBach and sometime it wont add any values..

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code

```
if (Session["confirmBooking"] != null && (string)Session["confirmBooking"] ==  "confirm" )
{
    if (Session["beachBach"] != null && (bool)(Session["beachBach"]) == true)
    {
        numberOfBeachBookingInteger += 1;
    }
    if (Session["bushBach"] != null && (bool)(Session["bushBach"]) == true)
    {
        numberOfBushBookingInteger += 1;
    }
}
```

seems that you need to check `"confirm"` session variable and also the `beachBach`, `bushBach` variables too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's where you're setting the session values:

```
// will set value to true or false
Session["beachBach"] = (bachRadioButtonList.SelectedValue != "Beach bach");

// will set value to true or false
Session["bushBach"] = (bachRadioButtonList.SelectedValue != "Bush bach");
```

Here's where you're retreiving them:

```
if (Session["beachBach"] != "confirm")  // will always fail because the session value is a boolean!
```

I suspect you want

```
if ((bool)(Session["beachBach"]) == true)  // the true is redundant but I add it here to be explicit
```

Comment: thanks for your help but

when i used if (Session["beachBach"] == true), the program gave an error saying that "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'bool'

Comment: You should always check that the session value exists and then cast the value to be sure it is actually the type you think it is before trying to use the value.

Comment: Added a cast to the answer.  You're already checking for null so as long as nothing else sets the value to something other than a bool you should be all right.

Comment: yeah... i think so too, so i just leave it like the code i did above, however, when i debug the program, it add 1 to the Session["beachBach"] but not ["bushBach"]